# Bitnami redmine change port number

Tags: redmine

We've installed [Bitnami redmine](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) on our Windows server and it's working fine at port 80.

Now we have installed some other server at the 80 port and we would like to change the port number of Redmine to say 90. I have been searching for last few days for this but I can't find a solution.

Where should we configure it in Bitnami or Redmine to make the application listen at a different port?

Answer (score 2):

Open up Apache2/conf/httpd.conf change Listen 80 to Listen 90

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
#Listen 80 --remarked out this line
Listen 90 --added this line
```

Comment: I have changed port like this. Previous port is 80. I have changed the port to 8888. Home page is opened. but http://localhost:8888/redmine/ says that 404 error. How to solve this?

Comment: In the case of bitnami installs, there is also a file `apache2\conf\bitnami\bitnami.conf` which should be edited.  Other installs probably have a similar config file.  Check httpd.conf for lines starting with "Include" and examine those config files.  Here, you'd be editing the `VirtualHost` nodes.